# Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6 does not detect startup USB for Mojave

Tags: macos, mojave

I would like to perform a clean install of Mojave as outlined in this article

https://setapp.com/how-to/clean-install-macos-mojave

However, my Mac Air 2013 does not detect my USB installer as a startup disk. I have tried twice to reformat the USB as macOS Extended Journaled and created a startup disk as outlined [here](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201372), but still no luck (see screen shots below.)

Most suggestions online suggest reformatting the USB (which I have already done), but it still does not pick up the USB. I have also tried rebooting in recovery mode without the usb being detected.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you tried (in terminal) `sudo reboot disk2s1`? If not, try re-making the bootable drive with http://dosdude1.com/apps/Mac%20OS%20X%20USB%20Drive%20Creator.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To boot from the USB Installer:

1. Power-up your Macbook
2. Hold down the Option key immediately after the chime sound
3. Choose Install macOS Mojave from the list of entries
4. Install macOS Mojave